# A positive number has a positive multiplicative inverse

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> I'm trying to prove that for all $a\in\Bbb{R}$ if $a>0$ then $a^{-1}>0$

I'm going for a direct proof, via axioms of real numbers.

For every $a\in\Bbb{R}$, there must be a *additive inverse* such that $$a+(-a)=0, a\in\Bbb{R}$$

This means that $-a<0$, if $-a+a<a$ ... $a>0$

Now $-a$ must have a *multiplicative inverse* such that $$-a\cdot (-a)^{-1}=1$$

now $-a^{-1}<0$, it follows (...*additive inverse )* that $$-a^{-1}+a^{-1}<a^{-1}$$$$0<a^{-1}$$$$a^{-1}>0$$

What are the flaws in this proof?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $x<0\implies x^{-1}<0$. This is true, of course, but it is as hard to prove as what you want to prove.

Comment: Shouldn't the multiplicative inverse for $-a$ be $(-a)^{-1}$? You are taking $-(a^{-1})$ as a multiplicative inverse for $-a$ where it doesn't seem clear a priori that it is actually a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: I see. I suppose I should assume $a^{-1}<0$, then show $a<0$, knowing that the inverse can't be zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before you attempt to prove something is positive, it might help if you begin with *axioms* which define what 'positive' means.  I have an Analysis text which gives the following axioms:

**There is a subset of the Real Numbers called 'positive' which satisfies the following properties: (1) For every Real Number x, either x is positive or x is $0$ or -x is positive (and only one of these conditions holds); (2) Any sum or product of finitely many positive numbers is positive.**

*[Note: It then defines '$a > b$' as '($a - b$) is positive']*

From this we can first show that 1 is positive and -1 is not *(exercise left for the student)*.  Afterwards we assume $a$ is positive, hence NOT '$a$ is $0$', so $a^{-1}$ exists and $a \times a^{-1} = 1$ *(by definition)*.  By condition (1), either $a^{-1}$ is positive or $a^{-1}$ is $0$ or $-(a^{-1})$ is positive.  If $a^{-1}$ is $0$ then by (2), $a \times a^{-1} = a \times 0 = 0$, contradicting $a \times a^{-1} = 1$; if $-(a^{-1})$ is positive, by (2) $a \times -(a^{-1}) = -(a \times a^{-1}) = -1$ is positive, which it is not.  By exclusivity the only remaining possibility is $a^{-1}$ is positive.  QED