# Proving that the inverse of a positive number in some ordered field $S$ is still positive

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, relations, ordered-fields

I know there was a question previously posted about proving something like this for the reals:
[A positive number has a positive multiplicative inverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510218/a-positive-number-has-a-positive-multiplicative-inverse)

But I wanted to know how to do this for any ordered field $S$ with a total ordering $\sim$ so that $a\sim b\Rightarrow a+c\sim b+c$ for $a,b,c$ in $S$ and if $0 \sim a,b$, then so is its product, $0 \sim ab$

I'm pretty sure the $\sim$ is meant to be $≤$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F$ be an ordered field, so there is some set $P\subset F$ (of positives), such that if $x,y\in P$, then $x+y,xy\in P$, and $P$ satisfies the trichotomy axiom. Note if you define an ordered field as a set with a relation $<$ then $P=\{x:0<x\}$.

Note that you must first prove that $1\in P$ (so $-1\notin P$ by trichotomy). This is easily by contradiction, if we assume that $1\notin P$, then by trichotomy, we will have that $-1\in P$, but then $-1\cdot -1=1\in P$ (as it is the product of two positive numbers), but this contradicts that $1\notin P$. Thus, we conclude that $1\in P$ and $-1\notin P$.

Now let us show that if $x\in P$, then $x^{-1}\in P$. Assume for sake of contradiction that $x^{-1}\notin P$, then $-x^{-1}\in P$, and we will have that $x(-x^{-1})=-1\in P$ a contradiction. Thus, we conclude that $x^{-1}\in P$.